# Is “to” needed here? “We thank (to) our teacher”

Tags: prepositions

Could you please tell me if "to" is needed with "thank":

> We thank our teacher for everything she has done.

Or,

> We thank to our teacher for everything she has done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb "thank" is transitive. That means it has a direct object. The direct object  of "thank" is the person being thanked. The correct sentence is

> We thank our teacher...

But, "thank" can also be a noun in some situations.  For example

> We offer our thanks to our teacher...